# Python Scraping bot Adidas

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests, bots

I am writing a bot for adidas for a personal project, but I am blocked. How can I overcome this?

My code:

```
import requests

url = 'https://www.adidas.com.tr/en/predator-edge.4-turf-boots/GX0010.html'
headers = {
        "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/114.0.0.0 Safari/537.36",
}
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
print(response.text)
```

`

I need to take the incoming page and parse it, but the error returned to me:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale = 1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <title>adidas</title>

    <link href="/WAFfailoverassets/style.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
</head>
<body>

<main class="content-wrapper">
    <header class="top">
        <div class="logo">adidas</div>
        <span id="ctl00_mainContentPlaceHolder_lblInvalidRequest">
<br/> Reference Error: 18.a4e1202.1686570590.149c3b8a </span>
        <h1 class="title">Unfortunately we are unable to give you access to our site at this time. </h1>
        <p>A security issue was automatically identified, when you tried to access the website.</p>
    </header>

    <div class="columns">

        <section class="column column-1">
            <h3>What could have caused this?</h3>
            <p>During high-traffic product releases we have extra security in place to prevent bots entering our site. We do this to protect customers and to give everyone a fair chance of getting the sneakers. Something in your setup must have triggered our security system, so we cannot allow you onto the site.</p>
        </section>
.
.
.
```

Comment: "During high-traffic product releases we have extra security in place to prevent bots entering our site. We do this to protect customers and to give everyone a fair chance of getting the sneakers. Something in your setup must have triggered our security system, so we cannot allow you onto the site." Please abide by their wishes, they do not want you scraping their site.

Answer (score 0):

Alright what it looks like is adidas probably only allows requests to be made through a browser as part of their bot protection, since you're running it through python with a very simple request, you have been flagged as a bot.
You will need to trick adidas that you are the browser making a legitimate request. Hope this answers your question.

Comment: I guess that's where the problem comes in. How can I do that. I tried several session methods but it didn't work...